# Laravel 8 'Undefined variable: pageTitle' on a controller variable

Tags: php, laravel

I created a variable in my controller so I can inject a Page Title to my pages.  I have other variables setup exactly the same way and they work, but for some reason I am getting an `Undefined variable: pageTitle` on the new variable.

**ShowUsers.php**

```
public function render()
{
    ...

    return view('livewire.show-users', [
        'users' => $query->with('documents')->paginate($this->perPage),
        'currentUser' => auth()->user(),
        'pageTitle' => 'Users',
    ]);
}
```

**page-header.blade.php**

```
...

<h1 class="ml-3 text-2xl font-bold leading-7 text-gray-900 sm:leading-9 sm:truncate">
    {{ $pageTitle }}
</h1>

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding variable `pageTitle` into the `page-header` blade file. You can bind variables using Laravel Blade.

**liveware/show-users.blade.php**

```
@extends('page-header', ['pageTitle' => 'Users'])
```